# Unable to fetch data from custom api for the sitemap

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, sitemap

I have the below code in the sitemap.js file and I am getting XML format results on the page but the problem is with fetching data from backend API. The list function is inside the actions folder that returns a list of all blogs. Now I want to use it here and map through it and want to get a valid list of links in the sitemap

```
import { SitemapStream, streamToPromise } from 'sitemap';
import {list} from '../../actions/job';

export default async (req, res) =>{

    try {

        const smStream = new SitemapStream({
            hostname: `http://localhost:3000`,
            cacheTime: 600000,
          });
         
          const jobs=[list]
          jobs.forEach(job => {
            smStream.write({
              url: `/jobs/${job.slug}`,
              changefreq: 'daily',
              priority: 0.9
            });
          });

          smStream.end();

          const sitemapOutput = (await streamToPromise(smStream)).toString();
          res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
          });

          res.end(sitemapOutput);
    } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    res.send(JSON.stringify(e))
    }
}
```

The results look like this:
[image]

Comment: It looks like `job` doesn't have a `slug` field. Can you verify what you get with the `list` you are importing?

Comment: i actually used the list function on another page also it has slug .I am facing this in this file  only which is inside pages/api.

Comment: So, do you have slug under the items of the list here or not, is what I am trying to learn

Comment: yeah, it is there but I think maybe the issue is with this API folder.I tried to use hooks in this file but it is giving an error of invalid hooks call.I already used this function and used slug from it

Comment: Isn't this `list` already an array? Why so you put it inside another array with `[list]`? Just iterate over `list` directly.